# Need to exclude specific folders with Powershell Get-Childitem

Tags: powershell

i want to create a .csv list of some folders in a giant directory (1400+ folders and subfolders, more than 6TB). I need to list the Fullname, creation date, last access time and last write time. Yesterday i have managed to extract some folders, but then it stopped (PC went to sleep...). The .csv that the script created got almost 1GB big, which isn't the problem. The real problem is that i don't want to list those files again.

Here is my script, that i used:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path P:\ -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Sort-Object -Property FullName,Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime | Select-Object FullName,Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime  | Export-Csv -Path C:\...\*.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I've tried some `-Exclude`-Parameters but that didnt work. The output file always is 0KB.

Is there a way to exclude the folders, that already got listet? The remaining 1300+ folders would be  too much to insert them manually. I've tried to create a .txt list, merged them side-by-side (with Ubuntu) but that also didn't work, because of the missing backslash in the path name, like `P:\folder\` (the last backslash is always missing).

The last option is to insert every path manually, which also could be automated, but i don't know how.

Comment: Stick a `Select -Skip $N` into the pipeline just before `Export-Csv`, where `$N` is the number of entries you already have in your csv

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i'll try that!